# In Flutter, how to store value returned by FutureBuilder, Future async function in a String type variable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am using one String type variable e.g. `String API_URL= "http://www.example.com";` Now I want set API_URL value to set by returned from internet. So I am trying Future getURL() async{...} function but I am not sure how to store return value in variable and how my app will wait until its value getting stored in this variable. I have no code to show. So please help with a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: http.get(yourUrl),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
       if(snapshot.hasData){

//Your code..mayb return a listView builder.

}
}
)
```

Update 1

You can initialise the String in an `async` function and then call the function in `initState ()`

Comment: But I want to store it in variable like String API_URL = Get_API_URL();

Comment: OK, Thanks. I will try in that way.